# How do I get the name tag of an instance in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

With this code, I can list all the tags in the first slot of all my instances. But what I want to do is get the name tag for each instance and store it in an array.

```
ec2.describeInstances(function(err, result) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                var inst_id = '-';
                for (var i = 0; i < result.Reservations.length; i++) {
                    var res = result.Reservations[i];
                    var instances = res.Instances;
                    for (var j = 0; j < instances.length; j++) {
                        var tagArr = instances[j].Tags[0];

                        console.log(tagArr);                            
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is the result I get:

```
{ Key: 'Name', Value: 'name1' }
{ Key: 'Name', Value: 'name2' }
{ Key: 'Name', Value: 'name3' }
{ Key: 'MigrationDate', Value: '2016-07-03' }
{ Key: 'Billing', Value: 'Bill' }
{ Key: 'Name', Value: 'name4' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my own issue. :)

```
ec2.describeInstances(function(err, result) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err); // Logs error message.
                var inst_id = '-';
                for (var i = 0; i < result.Reservations.length; i++) {
                    var res = result.Reservations[i];
                    var instances = res.Instances;
                    for (var j = 0; j < instances.length; j++) {
                        var instanceID = instances[j].InstanceId;
                        var tags = instances[j].Tags;
                        for (var k = 0; k < tags.length; k++) {
                          if (tags[k].Key == 'Name') {
                            var params = {
                              InstanceId: instanceID, /* required */
                              Name: tags[k].Value, /* required */
                              Description: 'Testing AMI Node3',
                              DryRun: false,
                              NoReboot: true
                            };
                            ec2.createImage(params, function(err, data) {
                              if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
                              else     console.log(data);
                            });                                
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```